# plot returns discontinuous lines (with gaps) in R when using spectacles package

Tags: r, spectra

**UPDATE ABOUT SOLUTION:**
set argument gaps = F in your plot() command
            `library(spectacles)
spectra(your_data) <- sr_no ~ ... ~ 350:2500 # turn your data frame to Spectra* object with the spectrum range of your interest
plot(your_data, gaps = F) # return plot with no gaps or line discontinuously`

#

I have to work with a Spectra* object and plot with the code as similar as this, just changing buil-in "australia" data frame by my data:

```
library(spectacles)    
data(australia)     
spectra(australia) <- sr_no ~ ... ~ 350:2500    
s <- cut(australia, wl =c(-1*450:500, -1*1800:2050))    
plot(s)
```

My plot in R returned discontinuously as the attached image below. Data frame's dimension is 150 rows, 3156 columns. The problem remains when I reduced df to 1800 columns.

Has anyone had the same problems? Could you suggest a solution? Thank you so much in advance!

[image: Plotting wavenumber vs abs value]

Comment: @LB. can you also provide us with the output error, if there is one.  It may be a simple solution, keeping the columns as the original value, and **not** using 1800, and **re-sizing** the plot view window i.e. making it bigger, so that the plot will fit the window.  This is why I was asking about the error.  Sometimes the plot window is too small for the graph being generated.

Comment: @Dave2e Yes I edited questions with the code above. Thank you in advance!

Comment: @ConradThiele there's no error returns when I executed the code. I also plot with all data and still got the same problems. I tried to improve the margin with par(mar=c(3.0, 3.0, 1.5, 1.5)) but it didn't help. Do you have other recommendation for resize the plot view window? Thank you!

Comment: I am at a lose, sorry to ask, but how did you download this australia dataset?  That why I can install it and try some trouble shooting ideas.

Comment: @ConradThiele it's from package {spectacles} to analyse spectral data.
I don't have the same plotting problem with australia dataset. It just happens with my spectroscopy data.

Comment: Sorry mate, that is way too hard to figure out.

Comment: @ConradThiele yes I think I'll try the visual in another computer. anw thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Please bear with me as it is a lot easier to explain my question by visualization than to leave a comment.  Do you want to remove this data or are you wanting to cut a **portion** of the data?  See examples below.

```
s1 <- cut(australia, wl =c(-1*450:500, -1*1800:2050))
plot(s, gap=TRUE)
```

[image: Spectral minus 450:500 & 1800:2050]

Alternatively you could use the example for the help file in R.

```
library(ggplot)
data(australia)
spectra(australia) <- id ~ ... ~ 500:1800 # changed the range

r <- melt_spectra(australia)
australia$fact <- sample(LETTERS[1:3], size = nrow(australia), replace = TRUE)
r <- melt_spectra(australia, attr = 'fact')
p <- ggplot(r) + geom_line(aes(x=wl, y=nir, group=id, colour=fact)) + theme_bw()
print(p)
```

[image: Spectral image from 500:1800]

Alternative you can take a portion of the analysis.

```
s <- as(cut(australia, wl = 1*450:550), 'Spectra') 
plot(s)
```

[image: subset of spectra]

Comment: problem solved! It was the argument "gaps = F" in plot() of spectacles packages. By default gaps was set = T and I didn't notice, because I don't have same problem when trying with australia dataset. Thank you so much!